# Stored procedure with conditional insert

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I am trying to write a procedure with an `If` statement.

This is my database

[image: DataBase]

My idea is: when we have same `ComandmentNumber`, `StudentNumber` must increase by 1, but when we have new `ComandmentNumber`, `StudentNumber` must start from 1.

Example:

[image]

Here is my procedure in SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIntoDefeatsGraduates
    @ComandmentNumber VARCHAR(100),
    @StudentFakNumber INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StudentNumber INT 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] 
               WHERE ComandmentNumber = @ComandmentNumber) 
    BEGIN
        SET @StudentNumber += 1

        INSERT INTO dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] (ComandmentNumber, StudentNumber, StudentFakNumber) 
        VALUES (@ComandmentNumber, @StudentNumber, @StudentFakNumber)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @StudentNumber = 1

        INSERT INTO dbo.[Defeats-Graduates](ComandmentNumber, StudentNumber, StudentFakNumber) 
        VALUES (@ComandmentNumber, @StudentNumber, @StudentFakNumber)
    END
END
```

But when I try to execute this, I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StudentNumber', table 'Test.dbo.Defeats-Graduates'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no assignment statements for `@StudentNumber` in the first condition, You can try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertIntoDefeatsGraduates
    @ComandmentNumber VARCHAR(100),
    @StudentFakNumber INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StudentNumber INT 
    SELECT @StudentNumber = StudentNumber  FROM dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] 
               WHERE ComandmentNumber = @ComandmentNumber
    IF ISNULL(@StudentNumber, 0) > 0
      BEGIN
        SET @StudentNumber += 1

        INSERT INTO dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] (ComandmentNumber, StudentNumber, StudentFakNumber) 
        VALUES (@ComandmentNumber, @StudentNumber, @StudentFakNumber)
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        SET @StudentNumber = 1

        INSERT INTO dbo.[Defeats-Graduates](ComandmentNumber, StudentNumber, StudentFakNumber) 
        VALUES (@ComandmentNumber, @StudentNumber, @StudentFakNumber)
      END
    END
```

Comment: nope, in that case,  the `@StudentNumber` already have an value that > 0.

Comment: Actually, `SELECT @StudentNumber = StudentNumber  FROM dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] WHERE ComandmentNumber = @ComandmentNumber` will initialize `@StudentNumber` if any record matched.

Answer (score 3):

You never **initialize** your `@StudentNumber` - you just declare it - then it's `NULL` - and adding `+1` to `NULL` still remains `NULL` - so in the end, you're trying to insert `NULL` into your table

```
-- at this point, @StudentNumber is NULL 
DECLARE @StudentNumber INT 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] 
           WHERE ComandmentNumber = @ComandmentNumber) 
BEGIN
    -- trying to increment a NULL value still results in NULL
    SET @StudentNumber += 1

    -- here you're about to insert NULL into "StudentNumber"
    INSERT INTO dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] (ComandmentNumber, StudentNumber, StudentFakNumber) 
    VALUES (@ComandmentNumber, @StudentNumber, @StudentFakNumber)
```

What you need to do is **read the actual value** in the case it exists:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] 
           WHERE ComandmentNumber = @ComandmentNumber) 
BEGIN
    -- get the highest value and increment by one
    SELECT @StudentNumber = MAX(StudentNumber) + 1
    FROM dbo.[Defeats-Graduates] 
    WHERE ComandmentNumber = @ComandmentNumber;
```

**BE AWARE**: the `SELECT MAX()+1` approach is **very vulnerable** to producing duplicate values, if you have a busy system with multiple clients working and inserting data at the same time. Whenever possible, you should use a proper **database-provided** mechanism instead - something like a `SEQUENCE` in SQL Server or something similar, that is designed and built to provide unique values, even under intense work loads.